# Can we connect RabbitMq directly from Angular Application

Tags: angular, browser, rabbitmq, amqp

In my current Angular project , have requirement to connect RabbitMq server queue. I have tried amqp, amqp-ts npm librarires but those are node applications. cant able to work with browser side application.

Is there any library that provide direct RabbitMq connection from Angular app ? is it the right way to do this ?